# Is it valid to use boolean literals in preprocessor conditionals?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer

Consider the following code, which results in the boolean literal `true` being evaluated in a preprocessor conditional:

```
#define SOME_MACRO true

int main ()
{
#if SOME_MACRO
  return 1;
#else
  return 0;
#endif
}
```

Clang 3.4 and GCC 4.8 both accept this code, even with `-pedantic -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra`.

Visual Studio 2013 rejects it, with [fatal error C1017: invalid integer constant expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5sh3k99.aspx).

My reading of [n3376](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) §
16.1 is that the regular C++ rules for evaluating constant expressions should apply.

If so, this code is valid, and it's a bug if MSVC does not accept it.

But I don't find the standardeze particularly clear. Could someone confirm this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is valid. See C++11 §16.1/4 (emphasis mine)

> Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become the controlling
>   constant expression are replaced (except for those macro names modified by the `defined` unary operator),
>   just as in normal text. If the token `defined` is generated as a result of this replacement process or use
>   of the `defined` unary operator does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro replacement,
>   the behavior is undefined. After all replacements due to macro expansion and the `defined` unary operator
>   have been performed, **all remaining identifiers and keywords, except for `true` and `false`, are replaced
>   with the pp-number `0`**, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens
>   comprise the controlling constant expression which is evaluated according to the rules of 5.19 using arithmetic
>   that has at least the ranges specified in 18.3. For the purposes of this token conversion and evaluation all
>   signed and unsigned integer types act as if they have the same representation as, respectively, `intmax_t`
>   or `uintmax_t` (18.4). This includes interpreting character literals, which may involve converting escape
>   sequences into execution character set members. Whether the numeric value for these character literals
>   matches the value obtained when an identical character literal occurs in an expression (other than within a
>   `#if` or `#elif` directive) is implementation-defined. Also, whether a single-character character literal may
>   have a negative value is implementation-defined. **Each subexpression with type `bool` is subjected to integral
>   promotion before processing continues.**

Comment: do you know if this was also true in C++98? This paragraph is identical to C99 except for having the text "except for true and false" added in.

Comment: @MattMcNabb there's a very similar paragraph in C++03. I don't know about C++98 but I would assume it's the same as C++03.

Comment: It is the same in C++98.